# jquery-ui button selection with firefox and internet explorer

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-selectors, uibutton

Hey the following code works with chrome,safari and opera without problem. But it does  work neither with firefox nor internet explorer.

Thanks for  help!!!

`$("#myButton" ).button(
    {icons: {primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus",secondary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"}});
$( "#myButton .ui-icon-circle-plus").click(
    function(){alert("myButton");})`

You can find the example in the following link:http://jsfiddle.net/asiaminor/suw0xs89/

Answer (score 0):

That's because the browser hasn't yet finished rendering your jQueryUI styles, and your selector can't match anything in the DOM. Use [Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$( "#myButton" ).click( ".ui-icon-circle-plus", function(){alert("myButton");})
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/40f5rmL2/)